# CSS selectors apply style to all images except the first one

Tags: css, css-selectors

I thought I could do this with advanced CSS selectors, but struggling.

I have a JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7HZEK/1/) with the below example

Basically, how can I target every image here, except the first one? I don't want to use classes or IDs, I just want to use advanced selectors, if possible.

So something like .entry-content img:first-child (although I know that wouldn't work)

```
<div class='entry-content'>
    <div>
        <img src='http://placedog.com/400/300'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='http://placedog.com/400/300'/>
    </div>        
     <div>
        <img src='http://placedog.com/400/300'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to select all img tags except first one use `:not` subclass:

```
.entry-content div:not(:first-child) img
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GrAaA/

Browser support:
`:not` http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot
`:first-child` http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Afirst-child

Comment: Great, this seems like the cleanest solution. Thanks everyone else for their help

Comment: If you care about browser support, you could use this method anyway and then plug http://selectivizr.com/ to your project

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to exclude the image in the first `div` child, rather than just the first `img` child, as every `img` is the first and only child of its `div` while the `div` elements themselves are siblings.

To do that, you can use this selector:

```
.entry-content div + div img
```

This selects the image in every `div` that comes directly after another `div`, so your first one won't be matched.

If you have siblings other than `div` within `.entry-content` you may need to use the general sibling selector instead:

```
.entry-content div ~ div img
```

Comment: Hi BoltClock, is there any way to make this more robust, since sticking a paragraph in breaks that e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/7HZEK/5/

Comment: @SparrwHawk: You can use `~` instead of `+`, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/7HZEK/6 I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

apply a style to all the images. then apply a style to the first child that negates the other styles. make sure the style for the first child is after the styles for the other images in your stylesheet so that they are applied by the browser in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
.entry-content div:first-child img {
     border: none;
}​
```